# How to perform arithmatic operation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to perform a few arithmetic operations on few columns and after operations are get performed again I need to put down result in CSV. After adding result into CSV, resultant answer needs to compare with `total_sales_price` and accordingly output will shown as true or false.

Please refer my code suggest me what should I need to do.

```
data = pd.read_csv('pandastest.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.head()
#Result = np.where(data.sales_price/(1-(data.margin_pct/100)))
df['Result'] = (df['sales_price']/(1-(df['margin_pct']/100)))
```

Comment: to put down the result into csv again use df.to_csv(). you can do the comparison of two columns also the same way or you can write a lambda or a function and use .apply() method. 

example :
df['comp'] = df['Result']==df['total_sale_price']

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the fields and store the result of comparison in your result column and then push it to a csv.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.head()
df['Result'] = df['total_sales_price'] == (df['sales_price']/(1-(df['margin_pct']/100)))
print(df['Result'])
df.to_csv("result.csv")
```